Prove $f'(r_{+}) + f'(r_{-}) < 0$ for roots of $1 - \frac{M}{r^2} + \frac{Q}{r^4} - r^2 = 0$

Problem. Let $M, Q > 0$ be given. Let
$$f(r) := 1 - \frac{M}{r^2} + \frac{Q}{r^4} - r^2, \quad r > 0.$$
If $f$ has three distinct positive real roots $r_c > r_{+} > r_{-} > 0$,
prove that $f'(r_{+}) + f'(r_{-}) < 0$.

This is a problem in alibaba global mathematics competition, June 22, 2024.
Edit. As pointed out by @mathlove, I made a mistake. I delete my attempt. Although I am sure I can do it along this way. But since @mathlove has given a proof. I do not do it.
Any other proofs?


Thus, we have $$r^6 - r^4 + Mr^2 - Q = (r^2 - r_c)(r^2 - r_{+})(r^2 - r_{-})$$

I think it should be
$$r^6 - r^4 + Mr^2 - Q = (r^2 - r_c^{\color{red}2})(r^2 - r_{+}^{\color{red}2})(r^2 - r_{-}^{\color{red}2})$$
We have
$$\begin{align}r_c^2+r_+^2+r_-^2&=1,
\\r_c^2r_+^2+r_+^2r_-^2+r_-^2r_c^2&=M,
\\r_c^2r_+^2r_-^2&=Q.\end{align}$$
As you did, let $p:=r_++r_-$ and $q:=r_+r_-$.
Since
$$\begin{align}M&=(1-p^2+2q)(p^2-2q)+q^2,
\\\\Q&=q^2(1-p^2+2q).\end{align}$$
we can write
$$\begin{align}&f'(r_{+}) + f'(r_{-})
\\\\&=\frac{2M(r_+^3+r_-^3)}{r_{+}^3r_-^3} - \frac{4Q(r_+^5+r_-^5)}{r_{+}^5r_-^5} - 2(r_{+}+r_-)
\\\\&=\underbrace{\frac{p(p^2 - 4 q) }{6q^3}}_{\text{positive}}\bigg(36\bigg(q-\frac{3p^2-1}{6}\bigg)^2+3p^4-6p^2-1\bigg)\end{align}$$
So, it suffices to prove that
$$F(q):=36\bigg(q-\frac{3p^2-1}{6}\bigg)^2+3p^4-6p^2-1\lt 0$$
We have
$$\begin{cases}p\gt 0,
\\q\gt 0,
\\M\gt 0,
\\Q\gt 0,
\\r_c\gt r_+,
\\p^2-4q\gt 0.\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}p\gt 0,
\\q\gt 0,
\\\frac{2p^2-1-\sqrt{p^4-p^2+1}}{3}\lt q\lt\frac{2p^2-1+\sqrt{p^4-p^2+1}}{3},
\\q\gt \frac{p^2-1}{2},
\\p\lt \frac{2\sqrt 3}{3}\ \text{and}\ q>\frac{4p^2-3+p\sqrt{3-2p^2}}{9},
\\q\lt \frac{p^2}{4}.\end{cases}$$
i.e.
$$\begin{cases}0\lt p\lt\frac{2\sqrt 3}{3},
\\\max\bigg(0,\frac{4p^2-3+p\sqrt{3-2p^2}}{9}\bigg)\lt q\lt \frac{p^2}{4}.\end{cases}$$
So, we have two cases to consider :
Case 1 : If $0\lt p\le\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}$ and $0\lt q\lt\frac{p^2}{4}$, then $F(q)\lt 0$ since $$F(0)=12p^2(p^2-1)\lt 0,$$
$$F\bigg(\frac{p^2}{4}\bigg)=\frac{21}{4} p^2\bigg(p^2-\frac{12}{7}\bigg)\lt 0$$
Case 2 : If $\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}\lt p\lt\frac{2\sqrt 3}{3}$ and $\frac{4p^2-3+p\sqrt{3-2p^2}}{9}\lt q\lt \frac{p^2}{4}$, then $F(q)\lt 0$ since
$$F\bigg(\frac{4p^2-3+p\sqrt{3-2p^2}}{9}\bigg)=\frac{-4p}{9}\bigg((p^2 + 3)\sqrt{3 - 2 p^2} + 5p\bigg(\frac{9}{5}-p^2\bigg)\bigg)\lt 0,$$
$$F\bigg(\frac{p^2}{4}\bigg)=\frac{21}{4} p^2\bigg(p^2-\frac{12}{7}\bigg)\lt 0$$
Therefore, we finally can say that $f'(r_{+}) + f'(r_{-}) < 0$.

Thanks! I make a mistake.
